# How to get the value of textbox using id in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value of input boxes based on id and name.

Since my id is having comma its not accepting. When i remove comma and one of the id,it shows perfectly.

But, I will get the id as "Text,Demo_1" only. How can i get the value based on this id??

here is the code

HTML

```
<div id="Text,Demo_1" class="span12">
<label>Notes or Concerns</label>
<div class="control-group">
<input type="text" value="hi" name="view1" class="recommend">
<input type="text" value="hi2" name="view1" class="recommend">
<input type="text" value="hi3" name="view1" class="recommend">
</div>
</div>
```

Js part

```
$(function() {
        var values = $('#Text,Demo_1 input[name="view1"]').map(function() {
         return this.value;
 }).get();
alert(values);
});
```

Comment: Advise you to get rid of the `,` in your id, this might mess up jQuery. Change this `id="Text,Demo_1"` to (say) `id="TextDemo_1"`

Comment: Is a comma even allowed in an ID and why do you have one?

Comment: its generating automatically..i can do anything with that that???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to match the begining and end of the ID:

```
var values = $("div[id^='Text'][id$='Demo_1'] input[name='view1']").map(function() {
...
```

**Edit:** Explanation.

```
[id^='Text'] => Every element which id starts with "Text"
[id$='Demo_1'] => Every element which id ends with "Demo_1"
```

Putting them together will select every element that match both rules.

Answer (score 1):

**Get value by Name :**

```
$("[name='view1']").val()
```

**Get value by ID :**

```
$("#[textbox_ID]").val()
```

**Get all text values in array**

```
var inputTypes = [];

$('.control-group input[name="view1"]').each(function(){
     inputTypes.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array,

```
$(function () {
    var values = [];
    $('#TextDemo_1 input[name="view1"]').each(function () {
        values.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.dir(values);
});
```

Comment: my id is "Text,Demo_1"

Comment: Change your id, the `,` will cause problems with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You should escape your comma with `\\`

```
var values = $('#Text\\,Demo_1 input[name="view1"]').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/M8Jmz/

But while it works you should consider changing an id to a proper identifier.

Comment: Someone silently disagrees. Comment if you have reasonable objection.

Answer (score -1):

```
var values = $('input[name="view1"]').val();
```

Comment: This will only get the first value. Not sure if OP wants all three though.